# Python: How to refer to the same index value position in the two lists?

Tags: python

A total beginner here hi!
I have two lists:

```
month=['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

and

```
temperature=[-3.5, -4.5, -1.0, 4.0, 10.0, 15.0, 18.0, 16.0, 11.5, 6.0, 2.0, -1.5]
```

And my task is to get an output that says for example

> "The temperature in January was -3.5 degrees".

How do I get that result by defining the variable selectedMonth? No idea how to proceed!

I am able to define the index value to the first list, and the second seperately and via that get the result, but if I want to do it by just one index value (eg for January) for both lists?

Comment: Welcome! You can use `zip()`, look it up in the docs

Comment: zip() is a better way to do this but if you want to simply access the values you can use `print("The temperature in {} was {} degrees".format(month(x), temperature(x))` where x is the index of values you want to print

Comment: *sniff* do I smell homework?

Comment: Yes, homework for my second python class ever! Hence the being a beginner note :)

Comment: Don't you think you would learn more if you tried to find a solution and presented your failed attempts here? Then you will have thought about it in more depth, will learn from the replies, why it didn't work, and will get responses, how to approach the problem from a different angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it without using any `zip` by just using `index`. `month.index(selectedMonth)` will return the index of the `selectedMonth` which will be `0` for `'January'`. You will then have, `temperature[0]` which will give you the required temperature value.

```
selectedMonth = 'January'
print("The temperature in", selectedMonth, "was", temperature[month.index(selectedMonth)], "degrees")

> The temperature in January was -3.5 degrees
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help, you're gold!

Answer (score 5):

Use the `zip` builtin.

```
>>> month=['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
>>> temperature=[-3.5, -4.5, -1.0, 4.0, 10.0, 15.0, 18.0, 16.0, 11.5, 6.0, 2.0, -1.5]
>>> 
>>> for m, t in zip(month, temperature):
...     print('The temperature in {} was {} degrees.'.format(m, t))
... 
The temperature in January was -3.5 degrees.
The temperature in February was -4.5 degrees.
The temperature in March was -1.0 degrees.
The temperature in April was 4.0 degrees.
The temperature in May was 10.0 degrees.
The temperature in June was 15.0 degrees.
The temperature in July was 18.0 degrees.
The temperature in August was 16.0 degrees.
The temperature in September was 11.5 degrees.
The temperature in October was 6.0 degrees.
The temperature in November was 2.0 degrees.
The temperature in December was -1.5 degrees.
```

This works because `zip` gives you an (iterator over) the following list:

```
>>> list(zip(month, temperature))
[('January', -3.5), ('February', -4.5), ('March', -1.0), ('April', 4.0), ('May', 10.0), ('June', 15.0), ('July', 18.0), ('August', 16.0), ('September', 11.5), ('October', 6.0), ('November', 2.0), ('December', -1.5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do it like this:

```
month=['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
temperature=[-3.5, -4.5, -1.0, 4.0, 10.0, 15.0, 18.0, 16.0, 11.5, 6.0, 2.0, -1.5]

data = dict(zip(month, temperature))

# Usage:
selectedMonth = "October"
print("The temperature in", selectedMonth, "was", data[selectedMonth], "degrees")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was searching for! The zip method is I think more logical, but this was needed to be done via the selectedMonth variable.